# Display string variable when button hover on asp.net C# web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a string text in the code behind file(C#) in my web form asp.net c# when I mouse hover on a button like a small message, the relevant text taken from the database and I already taken it to a string variable in my .cs file. I only need to display that string variable when my mouse point over the button. Please help..!

Comment: You need to learn about CSS and JavaScript my friend. It's 2015, not 1995

Answer (score 2):

Usually why do you need to make things complex and hard to develop using code-behind when you can handle client-side events in your ASP.NET applications using jQuery.

For example, have a look at the following jQuery code

```
// upon mouse over
$('button').mouseover(function (){
    // alert the string 
    // you can write this string into DOM too
    alert('your string here');
});
```

You will be able to create your desired functionality in the application using the above code.